# Why does auth.log warn of a possible break in attempt?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, rsync

I have a server which receives backups from a remote server via `rsync` authenticated by ssh-keys. The rsync comes via a ddns URL, to a high numbered forwarded port.

The sending server is on a normal home internet line, fow which the ISP assigns a dynamic IP. The IP of the sending connection changed about a week ago, and since then, `/var/log/auth.log` has contained the following message every time the ssh connection is initiated. I've checked that the new IP address does belong to the site where the sending server is located.

```
Apr 11 08:30:15 someserver sshd[25447]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for hostXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.some.isp-name.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK IN ATTEMPT!
```

What's causing this warning, and is there anything I could/should have done to avoid it?

Comment: Probably the reverse DNS record for the new IP does not match the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment in the [code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/auth.c#L846) explains it well:

```
/*
 * Map it back to an IP address and check that the given
 * address actually is an address of this host.  This is
 * necessary because anyone with access to a name server can
 * define arbitrary names for an IP address. Mapping from
 * name to IP address can be trusted better (but can still be
 * fooled if the intruder has access to the name server of
 * the domain).
 */
```

Basically as descrbed in the comments. This is significant thread if you have access based on source IP (`HostBased` authentication). It is less significant if you have some filtering or so.

If you don't like this error, you can always use `UseDNS no` in your `sshd_config` and this message should go away.